# Identity Cookie not reading after a while

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My problem is valid only on the site I have published, Cookie works properly on localhost. However, after logging in to the site, it does not wait for the 1-day period it should wait.

```
public static void ConfigureCookie(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
        
        options.Cookie = new()
        {
            Name = "ta_cookie",
            HttpOnly = true,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
            SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
            IsEssential = true
        };
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    });
}
```

this is my code

```
var result = await _signInManager
                .PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.LoginModel.Password,
                    model.LoginModel.RememberMe, true);
            
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
```

I want a session that will last 1 day to start, just like on localhost. Otherwise, cookies can be used, but as I said, it end early.

[image: Set-cookie header]

[my site link](https://techarsiv.com/forum)

Could this be a cloudflare issue? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by adding this

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
});
```

to Program.cs

It was related with ISS btw.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).